# How to enter mathematical expressions inside the "sed" command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

given a list of numbers, I would like, through the "sed" command, to display only the lines in a range from 2 to a variable, to which 1 is subtracted. How can I subtract 1 to the variable inside the expression? I would not like solutions that create another variable before the command.

```
echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n" | sed -n "3,+$var p"
```

this show 3-4-5-6 if $var=3.
But if I wanted to print up to 5 (3-4-5), I would have to subtract 1 from the variable ($var-1).

I would like a way to insert ($var - 1)

Comment: To reinforce what anubhava was saying about `echo -e` being nonportable, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly the OPTIONS, APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections. `echo -e` isn't permitted by the standard to do anything but print `-e` on output. As the APPLICATION USAGE section states: *It is not possible to use `echo` portably across all POSIX systems unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$((...))` in shell for arithmetic avaulation:

```
echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n" | sed -n "3,+$((var-1)) p"
```

```
3
4
5
```

I suggest using `printf` as it is more portable:

```
printf '%s\n' {1..7} | sed -n "3,+$((var-1)) p"
```

In `bash` you can use `here-string` and avoid pipeline:

```
sed -n "3,+$((var-1)) p" <<< $'1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n'
```

Comment: `printf '%s\n' {1..7}` is an even terser alternative.

Comment: @anubhava Perfect, it works, thank you !!! Could you tell me why you suggest printf?

Comment: @Giupo, ...I actually just covered that in a comment on the question, with links to the relevant standard. bash's `echo` is noncompliant with the POSIX sh standard *by default*, but it can be configured at either compile-time or runtime to comply, at which point `echo -e` will print `-e` on output. And of course scripts you write assuming `echo -e` will work the way you expect aren't guaranteed to function correctly on other shells at all.

Comment: @anubhava ...btw, the "in bash" qualifier isn't really  strictly needed, with `$(( ... ))` being POSIX-specified syntax.

Comment: thank you very much, I will go into this question! :)